# Quartz Job and Group Name - Encryption

Tags: quartz-scheduler

We are using Quartz for scheduling. Somehow, whoever implemented it used some sensitive information for `Job Name` and `Group Name`. Now as part of a new requirements we have to encrypt all the sensitive data which means we need to encrypt the job and group names as well.

Does it make sense to encrypt this information? My understanding is that Quartz just needs something unique to identify the jobs and it can be an encrypted value, but I'm not sure if there would be any performance impact.

Any thoughts?

Note: I cannot change the way Quartz has been implemented so I have to keep using sensitive information in job and group name. So I'm looking for some other way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Job and Group names are just java Strings, they can be whatever values you like. There will be no performance impact of using one String value over another that I can see.

On the other hand trying to monitor and debug your program with mangled and meaningless values will be more difficult.